# Notation classifying topos

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, topos-theory

The classifying topos of a geometric theory $\mathbb T$ is a topos $\mathcal E_\mathbb T$ such that for any other Grothendieck topos $\mathcal E$, the category of geometric morphisms from $\mathcal E_\mathbb T$ to $\mathcal E$ (or the other way round -- I tend to confuse the direction of geometric morphisms) is equivalent to the $\mathbb T$-models in $\mathcal E$.

I noticed that in a [document of Caramello](https://www.oliviacaramello.com/Unification/ToposTheoreticPreliminariesOliviaCaramello.pdf) (which I think is part of her book *Theories, Sites, Toposes*) a different notation is used: the classifying topos of $\mathbb T$ is denoted by $\mathbf{Set}[\mathbb T]$ instead of $\mathcal E_\mathbb T$.

**Question:** In which sense can the classifying topos of $\mathbb T$ be viewed as *adjoining* $\mathbb T$ to the category $\mathbf{Set}$ of *sets*?

Comment: I'd say we're not adjoining $\mathbb T$ to the topos of sets but rather adjoining a generic model of $\mathbb T$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is indeed a strong analogy between this situation and adjoining a polynomial variable to a ring, except that the direction of the arrows is somewhat messed up:

A ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[X] \to R$ is the same thing as a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to R$ (of which there is exactly one) together with one arbitrarily chosen element of $R$. (More precisely, we have a bijection, natural in the ring $R$.)

A geometric morphism $\mathcal{E} \to \mathrm{Set}[\mathbb{T}]$ is the same thing as a geometric morphism $\mathcal{E} \to \mathrm{Set}$ (of which there is exactly one, up to unique isomorphism) together with one arbitrarily chosen $\mathbb{T}$-model in $\mathcal{E}$. (More precisely, we have an equivalence of categories, natural in the topos $\mathcal{E}$.)

In case you wonder how to adjoin a $\mathbb{T}$-model to another topos than $\mathrm{Set}$, you can simply take the product $\mathcal{E}[\mathbb{T}] = \mathcal{E} \times \mathrm{Set}[\mathbb{T}]$, just like we have $R[X] = R \otimes \mathbb{Z}[X]$. (But be aware that the product of toposes is *not* given by the product of the underlying categories.) (And one could generalize to the case where $\mathbb{T}$ is not an ordinary geometric theory but instead a geometric theory internal to $\mathcal{E}$.)

In case you wonder, if you can adjoin a model of an arbitrary geometric theory to a topos, then what else can you adjoin to a ring apart from just a new ring element: you could for example "adjoin" two elements $X$ and $Y$ with the property that $X^2 = 5Y$; this would yield $R[X, Y]/(X^2 - 5Y)$. But the analogy arguably starts breaking down here.

The fact that the geometric morphisms go in the opposite direction from the ring homomorphisms (and that we use the product of toposes where we used the tensor product (coproduct) of rings) can be explained by saying that toposes are "geometric" objects and rings are "algebraic" objects. Or alternatively by the observation that while an element of a ring can be "pushed forward" along a ring homomorphism, a $\mathbb{T}$-model in a topos can be pulled back along a geometric morphism.

Comment: I think some people give a different name to "the left adjoint in the geometric morphism" like "logical morphism" precisely for this reason

Comment: "But the analogy arguably starts breaking down here." why? can't you adjoin to a ring any set of variables *together* with a set of equations these variables should satisfy. I mean if you can adjoin X  and Y with the property that X2=5Y to the ring R and get R[X,Y]/(X2−5Y), can't you do that with every equation? Why does the analogy breaks down here?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi "I think some people give a different name to "the left adjoint in the geometric morphism" like "logical morphism" precisely for this reason" I don't think the left adjoint of a geometric morphism is a logical morphism of toposes.

Comment: @MatthiasHutzler I asked a few questions but then could answer them myself, so I deleted them ... there's one remaining though (see above). Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Re "Why does the analogy start breaking down here?": Well, maybe it doesn't. :-) I agree that geometric theories behave like "systems of equations" (a set of variables and a set of equations in these variables) under this analogy. And while a "system of equations" is just another name for a (not necessarily finite) presentation of some $R$-algebra, geometric theories can be seen as syntactic presentations for toposes.

Comment: On the other hand, I don't think the notation $R[\ldots]$ is used for systems of equations. And if for example we just divide out an ideal in $R$, I think you would usually not call that "adjoining" something.

Comment: Also, it makes sense to say that the equations in a "system of equations" correspond to the axioms of a theory. But then, what do the variables in the "system of equations" correspond to? Geometric theories consist more naturally of three layers instead of two: (1) sorts, (2) function- and relation symbols and (3) axioms. So are systems of equations more like *propositional* geometric theories (those with zero sorts), and rings more like *localic* toposes (or just locales)? These are the kind of questions I wanted to avoid. ;-)

Comment: @MatthiasHutzler Thank you very much for your great help! I learned a lot. :-)